# Product rule for distributions

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Suppose $f, g \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ and that $\partial_{x}f + \partial_{y}f=\partial_{x}g + \partial_{y}g=0$. I wish to evaluate the action

$$(\partial_{x}(fg) + \partial_{y}(fg), \phi) $$ where $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$. In the smooth setting, of course we can say $\partial_{x}(fg) + \partial_{y}(fg) =0$ by the usual product rule. I am wondering if there is a way to justify this equality in the distributional sense?

Formally I would like to say $\partial_{x}(fg) + \partial_{y}(fg) = f(\partial_{x}g + \partial_{y}g) + g(\partial_{x}f + \partial_{y}f) = 0$ but not sure if we can justify the first equality. The second equality makes sense because $\partial_{x} g + \partial_{y}g  = 0$ collapses into a smooth function (zero) so the product with $f$ makes sense (and similarly for $f$).

I suspect that it might not be possible since we cannot consistently define multiplication of continuous function with an arbitrary distribution.

Comment: @AnneBauval yes thank you

Comment: Yeah, distributions are not always very efficient with nonlinearities, you coukd regularize the fonctions instead.

Comment: But of course the simplest here is to write $f(x,y)= u(x-y)$ and the same for $g$.

Comment: @LL3.14 Sorry im not sure what you mean by your last comment. I understand that we can write $f$ and $g$ as a function of $x-y$ but what are you suggesting I do with this?

Comment: Because then $fg$ also verifies this, so the relation with the derivatives is verified as well

Comment: @LL3.14 oh, so you mean that we can write $fg = v(x-y)$ so we must have $\partial_{x}(fg) + \partial_{y}(fg)=0$?